# How to put a slideshow images in html (dreamweaver) with one day as a duration of image being changed?

Tags: html, dreamweaver

I have build a website using Dreamweaver.
I want to insert a slideshow (images) to my website.
The images needs to be auto-changed in duration 24hours.

To make it clear:
Let say I had choose 5 images for that slideshow.
Today, the first image must be shown, after 24hours, the image will be automatically changed to the second image, and until the 5 images are all shown, it will go back to the first image again.

Comment: dreamweaver is irrelevant in this case. You could use js to determine the date and call an image file with that date as a filename or something. With no code provided, it's not likely you will get much of a response here